# Django ORM time delta returns that the firld is not defined

Tags: django, orm, timedelta

from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta
Activity.objects.filter(last_response__lte=timezone.now()-timedelta(days=sla))

On executing it I am getting message that sla is not defined.
but my model contains both fields last_response and sla and defined as an integer.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.utils import timezone from datetime import timedelta 
Activity.objects.filter(last_response__lte=timezone.now()-timedelta(days=MODEL_NAME.sla))
```

You're just refering to the model field name, not by the model object field property. You have defined an sla variable so it is giving you an undefined error. Either access off your `obj.sla` directly or `sla = obj.sla`.